# Jenkins + Tomcat + Git + SSH setup

Tags: git, tomcat, jenkins, ssh

I have a Synology NAS running Tomcat. I deploy Jenkins within Tomcat.

I also use the same Synology NAS as my git server.

I access my Synology NAS using Cygwin and the command ssh MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP.

I am now trying to setup a Jenkins freestyle job to build one of my projects.

**Under the Source Code Management section, what would i put into the Repository URL box to get jenkins to see and clone from my git repo?**

What i have tried...

1) The ssh link to my git repo is ssh://MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP/~MY_ACCOUNT/git_repos/project.git. I have tried putting this into the Repository URL box but i the error message below...

*Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP/~MY_ACCOUNT/git_repos/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

2) I have tried adding a execute shell under Build section. ssh MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP "git clone git_repos/project.git" but i get the error message below.

*Started by user JenkinsUser1
Building in workspace /volume1/@appstore/jenkins/workspace/Test1
[Test1] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/packages/Tomcat7/target/src/temp/hudson4761299816395827713.sh
+ ssh MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP 'git clone git_repos/project.git'
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*

3) I have also tried generating ssh keys in the /var/services/web/.ssh folder using root access to my Synology NAS (My Jenkins SystemInfo page shows HOME to be /var/services/web, also USER is set to be Http btw)
I copied the public key to ~MY_ACCOUNT/.ssh/authorized_keys.(where my git repos are stored)

4) As a litmus test i tried building a github project and it built successfully.

Any thoughts, help, advice welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a **shh authentication issue**. You have to keep first solution and set up ***credentials*** into Jenkins and use it to connect to your Git repository.

You may find some details [there](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/10/jenkins-git-setup/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20(The%20Geek%20Stuff)), under *"Setup Jenkins Credentials for Git"* section.

If problems persists try to connect a first time from Jenkins user onto git server in order to answer the question about RAS/Known host

Comment: Thanks for the help. My jenkins user is set to http. I have worked out how to generate ssh keys using http user now. Before i was using root user, which is wrong. Now i have valid ssh keys for http. I think the problem is with this line "ssh://MY_ACCOUNT@MY_IP/~MY_ACCOUNT/git_repos/project.git HEAD"  Both my git repos and jenkins are on the same machine. I think i need to try a path relative to the workspace where jenkins clones the git repo. So something like ../../MY/PATH/TO/LOCAL/REPOS/git_repos/project.git. And give http user read/write access.